# Inline <P style>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to inline style the SQL-data by using the following echo-line

```
   echo "<li> <a href = posts.php?id=" . $row['Id'] . "><p style='font-size:6pt'>" . $sDate . " - </p>" . $row['Titel'] . "<p style=color:red;font-size:6pt>nytt </p></a> </li>";
```

But the browser thinks there's a `<p>` in there and breaks the lines, I've been searching and trying many different solution but nothing really works.

Here's the entire code for the SQL-data.

```
     <?php include 'inc/db.php';

  $strSQL = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY id DESC");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($strSQL)) {

            $oDate = strtotime($row['Date']);
            $sDate = date("Y-m-d",$oDate);

           if ( date('Y-m-d') == $sDate )
           {

           echo "<li> <a href = posts.php?id=" . $row['Id'] . "><p style='font-size:6pt'>" . $sDate . " - </p>" . $row['Titel'] . "<p style=color:red;font-size:6pt>nytt </p></a> </li>";
           }
           else
           {

           echo  "<li> <a href = posts.php?id=" . $row['Id'] . "><p style='font-size:6pt;'>" . $sDate . " - </p>" . $row['Titel'] . "</a> </li>";
           }
              }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: it looks like you're missing some quotes for your second paragraph's style attribute in the echo

Comment: How is your result HTML looking like?

Comment: Of course the browser thinks there is a `p` in there: You've put a `<p>` in there!

Comment: I also think like that browser, because I also see a `<p>` in your echo.

Comment: If you don't want to see that p, you can change it to a span.

Comment: The web is built with many different computer languages: HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, SQL... You first need to tell them apart. Your question has nothing to do with neither PHP nor SQL.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!, and yes it's bit of mix-up regarding languages, i will eventually clean it up to make it easier to look at and troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `<p>` elements then you can change them to `<span>` elements in your script like so:

```
if ( date('Y-m-d') == $sDate )
{
    echo "<li> <a href=\"posts.php?id=" . $row['Id'] . "\"><span style=\"font-size:6pt;\">" . $sDate . " - </span>" . $row['Titel'] . "<span style=\"color:red;font-size:6pt\">nytt </span></a> </li>";
}
else
{
    echo "<li> <a href=\"posts.php?id=" . $row['Id'] . "\"><span style=\"font-size:6pt;\">" . $sDate . " - </span>" . $row['Titel'] . "</a> </li>";
}
```

I've also added quotes around the attributes on your tags.

It may be better to use a CSS style sheet and use classes to style the spans rather then using inline style decelerations.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<p> 
to 
<span>
```

EG:

```
from:
<p style...
to
<span style
```

and this will stop new line breaks being created.

Alternatively in your CSS you can define;

```
p {
display:inline;
}
```

And this will also stop new lines being created, and they will act the same as span.

Beware however, that changing the CSS for p will affect all

tags throughout your document.